# eval filed decoded files with perl

Tags: perl, error-handling, try-catch, eval

here I'm reading a list of files in directory But I noticed that some files can't be decoded it throws an error with this line `$tap3->decode($tap_file)  or  die $tap3->error;`

each time im reading the new file if the file valid to decode then i will do list of changes on it and after that encode the file again, else if the file corrupted cannot  be decoded i will do another task but the script refused that

```
printDir(".");
sub printDir{
opendir(DIR, $_[0]);
my @files;
my @dirs;
(@files) = readdir(DIR);
foreach my $file (@files) {
    if (-f $file and substr($file,0,2) eq "CD")
    {
        my $tap3 = TAP3::Tap3edit->new;
        my $tap_file = $file;
        $result = $tap3->decode("tap_file"); ## decode key

        if ( defined  $result ) ## here if the file can be decoded then i do changes on it - then encode the file
        {
            ..
            ..
            tap3->encode($tap_file)  or  die $tap3->error;

        }else { ## here if the file courrpted "connot be  decoded" then i do another job ...
            ...
            ...
            $tap3->file_type("TAP");
            $tap3->version(3);
            $tap3->release(11);

            $tap3->structure($notific_struct);

            $tap3->encode($file) || die $tap3->error();

        }

    }

}
closedir(DIR);
}
```

but its looks like it does not work at `( defined  $result )`

Comment: I've tidied up the formatting of your code. You're welcome, of course, but please consider doing it yourself next time. Good formatting is an important tool in making your code as easy to understand as possible and when you're asking a large group of strangers to read and understand you code, it's a good idea to make that task as easy as possible.

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to ask a question. Where, exactly, did you need our help?

Comment: @DaveCross do you have any idea about how can i solve this ?

Comment: It is still unclear what the actual problem is. Code does not refuse things, and "looks like it does not work" is not helpful at all. Do you get an error message? If yes, what is it? Also, add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to your script and fix what they complain about.

Comment: im reading list of files in a directory , i have noticed some of them are corrupted so i just want to convert the corrupted to notification files else if the file can be decoded i will do the changes, if the file can be decode i will do changes and encode it again , else if the file courrpted as it it returns unkown file format "courrpted" i will convert it to notification file

Comment: You said that already. BUT WHAT IS YOUR PROBLEM?

Comment: @Holli i have simplified my question as much as i can , sorry for my bad but the problem is the lookup for file can/connot be decoded does not working also does not return error , please check i have updated the question

Comment: Are you sure about `"tap_file"` being the name of the file you want to decode? Do you mean  `$result = $tap3->decode($tap_file);`?

Comment: @clamp yes dear.

Comment: It will help if you include all the required 'use', 'require', to make it possible to run. May be share the filename, and content of the file that can be decoded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using the tap error reporting to warn on the error.

```
       if ( defined  $result ) ## here if the file can not be decoded ...
        {
            ..
            ..
            tap3->encode($tap_file)  or  die $tap3->error;

        }else { ## here if the file courrpted "connot be  decoded" ...

            /// ADD THIS LINE
            warn "File: '$file_name' $tap3->error" ;
            /// CURRENT CODE FOLLOW
            $tap3->file_type("TAP");
            $tap3->version(3);
            ...
            .
        }
```

Comment: same thing it returns unknown file format cannot decode

Comment: @NikolanAsad - which file, what is the COMPLETE error message ? You probably want to check the specific file content (or share on SO, if you are unable to resolve yourself). Question should include MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example